# Can't connect to certain port - How to unblock port

Tags: windows, firewall, telnet, netbeans, xdebug

I am running a Apache2 Webserver with PHP 7 and xdebug. I try to establish a connection between my IDE (Netbeans) and xdebug running on my webserver.

I read [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html) that I have to check if I can connect to the client where the IDE runs

So I executed this command from my webserver, like recommended:

```
telnet 192.168.40.161 9000
```

**Hint:** 9000 is the port configured in php.ini for xdebug

**Result:**

```
Trying 192.168.40.161...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.40.161: Connection timed out
```

I configured the windows firewall like this:

[image]

[image]

Why does telnet fail to connect?

**More Infos:**

php.ini entry for xdebug:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = /usr/lib64/php7/extensions/xdebug.so
#zend_extension = /usr/lib64/php7/extensions/xdebug_2.6.so
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.force_display_errors=on
xdebug.force_error_reporting=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
#xdebug.remote_host=192.168.40.161

xdebug.remote_timeout=3000
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log
xdebug.idekey=A
xdebug.renite_enable = 1
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = '/var/log/xdebug'
```

Comment: If you completely disable the Windows firewall can you connect?

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio, I can't completly disable it, because only the sysadmin has the right. But I disabled it for public and private. I can't disable it for domain. Makes no difference.

Comment: Can you verify if your webserver is listening in port 9000?

Comment: I executed `netstat -a | grep 9000` but there is no result

Comment: Then xdebug is not running properly, Is it running with another port or it isn't running at all?

Comment: The port is 9000, it also creates a log entry in /var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log saying that the connection timed out after 3000 ms.

Comment: Is there any process running about xdebug? (I don't know how it works) If so, can you find an associated port via netstat?